# Typo3 add multilanguage support for template

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

i try to add multilanguage support for an typo3 page. I just want to load the contents, template translation is not required ATM.

i found out, that i would have to add those informations:

„css_styled_content“

```
 styles.content.get = CONTENT 
    styles.content.get { 
        table = tt_content 
        select.orderBy = sorting    
        select.where = colPos=0 
        select.languageField = sys_language_uid 
    }
```

the only hint i found in the template is this code:

```
subparts.CONTENTMITTE < styles.content.get
    subparts.CONTENTMITTE{
  renderObj  < plugin.tx_rgaccordion1
  renderObj.image.20.maxW = 495
  renderObj.textpic.20.maxW = 495
      renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="contentelement">|<div class="klearer"></div></div>
      }
```

is this the right spot to insert those informations?

what steps next? what do i need to do? will this auto detect the "?L=2" from the url?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Multilanguage should work out of the box with css_styled extension, so you don't need to change anything there.

The steps to enable multilanguage are pretty simple,

1. Add new web-site language to the root page
2. Create page / content translation
3. Configure the TS template
4. Add conditions that are switching the typo3 language in TS setup and that should do it.

Example of the TS setup (english is default- no need to add it, and German is with website language with id 1)

```
# Forcing the typo to display original elements where there are no translations 
config.sys_language_overlay = content_fallback     
# L is parameter that's used to determine the language, make it unique
config.linkVars = L , type

config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_EN

# English Language
[globalVar = GP:L =0]
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_EN

# German
[globalVar = GP:L =1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE
[global]
```

Comment: wow, thanks so far, this worked! Now I have 2 more questions:

- if i want to give the viewer the option to switch between languages, how can i add a link in the template 

"if the page is translated, give the viewer a link to domain.com/ OTHER_LANGUAGE / rest of the link" even if there is a /de/ in between or not

- if the system is only partially translated, how do i let the system generate the links in the site without /en/ in it or redirect to the /de/?

Comment: You need to use special case HMENU, here is an example for EN/DE languages : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/30d3966bf4e0b0af9a17

Comment: thanks, this worked perfectly fine! am i able to only show the link to the translations im not viewing atm? if im viewing fr than i want to see de and en. if im viewing de than fr and en so on.